# Equivalence principle and quantum gravity

Tags: quantum-gravity, equivalence-principle

Do new concepts  of gravity negate the validity of the equivalence principal?  or do all theories (waves, string, etc) and mathematics apply equally to gravitation and accelerating frames?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the equivalence principle is important in String Theory for example, which is a theory of gravity; it's already taken for granted that the graviton - the quantised particle for gravity is a spin-2 particle and its shown that the string theory spectrum has a spin-2 particle in its spectrum.